What is the Wrap-Around Phenomenon in FFT?
If I take FFT of a finite sequence and take longer length of IFFT of the frequency domain data by padding zeros with it, how will the wrap around of DFT effect the procedure? It would be great if anyone can give an idea of what actually the wrap around for FFT means.

By wrap around, are you referring to how the DFT is periodic, and asking how zero padding affects the period?

@Baddioes according to the procedure mentioned above, the final IFFT output should be a reflection of the original signal, to a longer length. My question is how the wrap around phenomena of DFT will effect the boundaries of the final IFFT, or if there should be any effect at all

Just like the reciprocal case of padding a time domain signal with zeros, but padding in frequency domain, you effectively interpolate.
You can think of it as if you’ve at a higher rate, and had no spectral energy in these higher frequencies.
Since you practically force a higher “Nyquist Frequency”, the supposed sampling interval is smaller, i.e., you interpolate in time domain.
Keep note, that if the zero padding isn’t smooth, in case you had some energy at the original Nyquist, you’ll end up having some ringing in time domain.
